# Mysql Stored Procedure: how to handle empty result set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a procedure in which one statement is not executing properly:

```
SELECT thumb_image into v_thumb_image FROM RESTAURANT_IMAGE WHERE 
   RESTAURANT_ID = v_restaurant_id
```

The reason, I investigated is if at any point of time resultset is empty, procedure doesn't run statements further.

Please note that I am calling this within a LOOP.

My concern is not to stop execution if for any `v_restaurant_id`, resultset is empty.

FULL PROCEDURE:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `populate_restaurant_details`()
BEGIN
 DECLARE v_finished_cuisines, 
         v_finished, 
         v_restaurant_id, 
         v_count_discount
 INT DEFAULT 0;

 DECLARE v_cuisines, 
         v_thumb_image 
 varchar(200) DEFAULT "";

 DECLARE cuisine_title varchar(50) DEFAULT "";
 -- Fetch all restaurant id
 DECLARE restaurant_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT id FROM delhifoodonline.restaurant order by id desc;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
  FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN restaurant_cursor;

 get_restaurant: LOOP   

   FETCH restaurant_cursor INTO v_restaurant_id;
   IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE get_restaurant;
   END IF;

  SET v_finished_cuisines =""; 
  SET v_thumb_image = "";
begin
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_thumb_image = NULL;

  SELECT thumb_image into v_thumb_image 
  FROM restaurant_image 
  WHERE restaurant_id = v_restaurant_id
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1;
end;

  SELECT count(*) into v_count_discount FROM restaurant_discount WHERE 
    restaurant_id = v_restaurant_id;

BLOCK2: BEGIN

  DECLARE cuisines_cursor CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT cuisine.title FROM restaurant_cuisine INNER JOIN cuisine 
    ON restaurant_cuisine.cuisine_id = cuisine.id
    WHERE 
    restaurant_cuisine.restaurant_id = v_restaurant_id
    LIMIT 0,5;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished_cuisines = 1;
  SET v_cuisines = "";
  OPEN cuisines_cursor;

  get_cuisine: LOOP
   FETCH cuisines_cursor INTO cuisine_title;

   IF v_finished_cuisines = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE get_cuisine;
   END IF;

   SET v_cuisines = CONCAT(cuisine_title,", ",v_cuisines);

   END LOOP get_cuisine;
  CLOSE cuisines_cursor;

END BLOCK2;

  SET v_cuisines = TRIM(BOTH ", " FROM v_cuisines);

  IF v_count_discount > 0 THEN
   SET v_count_discount = 1;
  ELSE
   SET v_count_discount = 0;
  END IF;

  UPDATE restaurant SET 
                        thumb_image = v_thumb_image,
                        cuisines_list = v_cuisines,
                        discount_available = v_count_discount
                   WHERE id= v_restaurant_id;
 END LOOP get_restaurant;

CLOSE restaurant_cursor;

END
```

Comment: The empty result set does not prevent the execution to continue. There should be some error in your further code when `v_thumb_image` is null. Please update your question and provide the code after the select.

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani, if I comment out this statement, procedure runs perfectly fine. I investigated & found that there are some `v_restaurant_id` for which there is no record in `restaurant_image table`. can you suggest something?

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani full code added.

Comment: Does restaurant table allow null thumb_image?

Comment: Be very careful as indicated in the documentation: `If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code 1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged.` - [13.2.9.1 SELECT ... INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). An example in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb3aeb/1).

Comment: @wchiquito, you are right but that should not stop execution of procedure.

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani, yes restaurant table allows null value in thumb_image.

Comment: How do you call your stored procedure. Using MySQL command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html):

> NOT FOUND is shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin
>   with '02'. This is relevant within the context of cursors and is used
>   to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data set.
>   If no more rows are available, a No Data condition occurs with
>   SQLSTATE value '02000'. To detect this condition, you can set up a
>   handler for it (or for a NOT FOUND condition). For an example, see
>   Section 13.6.6, “Cursors”. **This condition also occurs for SELECT ...
>   INTO var_list statements that retrieve no rows.**

So your select from `restaurant_image` table also meets the `NOT FOUND` state when it returns no rows, and invokes the defined handler which causes leaving the loop.

One solution is to declare another handler for that select by putting it inside a `BEGIN...END` block:

```
begin
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_thumb_image = NULL;

  SELECT thumb_image into v_thumb_image 
  FROM restaurant_image 
  WHERE restaurant_id = v_restaurant_id
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1;
end;
```

---

After all, why are doing that using a stored procedure and cursors which would be slow. You can achieve the same functionality executing a single statement:

```
UPDATE restaurant 
SET thumb_image = (
    SELECT thumb_image 
    FROM restaurant_image 
    WHERE restaurant_id = restaurant.id
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1),
discount_available = IF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM restaurant_discount 
    WHERE restaurant_id = restaurant.id), 1, 0), 
cuisines_list = (
    SELECT group_concat(cuisine.title separator ', ')
    FROM restaurant_cuisine
    INNER JOIN cuisine ON restaurant_cuisine.cuisine_id = cuisine.id
    WHERE restaurant_cuisine.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
    LIMIT 0,5)
```

Or make it even faster by eliminating sub queries for every row:

```
UPDATE restaurant r
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT restaurant_id, count(*) AS discount_available
    FROM restaurant_discount 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id) d ON r.id = d.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT restaurant_id, thumb_image 
    FROM restaurant_image r1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM restaurant_image r2 WHERE r2.restaurant_id = r1.restaurant_id AND r2.id < r1.id
    )) t ON r.id = t.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT rc.restaurant_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(c.title SEPARATOR ', '), ',', 5) AS cuisines_list
    FROM restaurant_cuisine rc
    INNER JOIN cuisine c ON rc.cuisine_id = c.id
    GROUP BY rc.restaurant_id
    ) rc ON r.id = rc.restaurant_id
SET r.discount_available = IF(d.discount_available = 0, 0, 1),
r.thumb_image = t.thumb_image,
r.cuisines_list = rc.cuisines_list
```

Try these sub-queries separately to find a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. every solution is working perfectly fine. I would like to go with single SQL statement. can you suggest me how can I update a column if there are many rows in relation table? I would like to keep all values in comma separated string.

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Amir, can you please update queries. I am little bit confused. Check BLOCK2 in procedure.